# Django-styled Flask URL pattern for large application

Tags: python, flask

I started off using Django building web apps, and now I'm depending on Flask for most of my projects. I think the decorator `@app.route` in Flask is straightforward, but once the file grows bigger and bigger, the "django style" url mapping seems to be more favorable.

To accomplish this, I used a work around to mimic Django's url mapping, but I'm not sure if this is a good practice and worried that there might be some performance issue.

Here is a minimal example:

```
# project/views.py
def index():
    print "hello index!"

def get_users():
    print "hello users!"

# project/urls.py
from project import views

# store url mapping arguments in a list of tuples following this pattern:
# (endpoint, methods, viewfunc)

urls = [
  ('/', ['GET'], views.index),
  ('/users', ['GET'], views.get_users)
]
```

Then finally:

```
# project/__init__.py
from flask import Flask
from project.urls import urls

app = Flask(__name__)
# Loop through the urls list to add all url rules to app
for url in urls:
    app.add_url_rule(url[0], methods=url[1], view_func=url[2])
```

This structure works with no problems and I see a cleaner organization of my code base, but somehow I feel unconfident having a `loop` inside my `__init__.py`.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Inspired by your question and Daniel Hepper's answer I've created a little flask package which addresses the problem in a generic way. https://github.com/jboegeholz/flaskurls Feel free to use or contribute

Comment: @JoernBoegeholz danke!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [set up an application factory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appfactories/):

```
def create_app(name):
    app = Flask(name)
    for url in urls:
        app.add_url_rule(url[0], methods=url[1], view_func=url[2])
    return app

app = create_app(__name__)
```